# Highcharts how to use js object in PHP widget

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

My question is similar to this one: [Highcharts how to use JavaScript variable as series data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751552/highcharts-how-to-use-javascript-variable-as-series-data-source) - except mine is a php variable.

I'm using https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget this package with Yii2 and I've generated a data array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => {y: 37.50, color: "#BF0B23"}
[1] => 49.25
[2] => 52
)
```

I cast the numbers to floats when generating this array, but I couldn't do this with the object. When the graph is rendered the columns all work fine except for the one that I am trying to change the colour for.

The JS ends up like this `"data":[37.5,49.25,"{y: 52.00, color: \"#BF0B23\"}"]`. The js object being quoted basically means it isn't rendered. I've tried `array_values()`, `(casting)` and some other weird and wonderful manipulation to try and remove the quotes. I'm hoping there is a way to easily remove the quotes?

Comment: Shouldn't there be: `Array(y=> 37.5, color=>"#BF0B23")` ? Of course `json_encode()` is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure out how to do it. Thanks @paweł-fus because your comment got me thinking about it a different way.

In my previous non-yii2, non 2amgios package I was generating my object as a string and writing it directly into JS.

```
    if($d['ATTENDING'] === $data['ATTENDING'])
            {
                $a[] = array($data['ATTENDING'] => '{y: ' . number_format($data['PERCENTAGE'], 2) . ', color: "#BF0B23"}');
            } else {
                $a[] = array($data['ATTENDING'] => number_format($data['PERCENTAGE'], 2));
            }
```

So my array either showed the column value, or if the column value was special it showed the value and i also changed its colour. This was represented as a JS object.

What I need to do was this though, create an inner array for the js object in php and typecast the value so it wasn't a string.:

```
    $a[] = array($data['ATTENDING'] => ['y' => (float) number_format($data['PERCENTAGE'], 2), 'color' => '#BF0B23']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to convert PHP hash into JSON, which then should be rendered by highcharts?

Try json_encode php function for that - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I tried json_encode() previously but it ended up generating `"data":"\"37.5,49.25,{y: 52.00, color: \\\"#BF0B23\\\"}\""`. It needs to be an array for Highcharts API

Comment: @Jonnny: So your issue is encoding the data property or charting it? Can you construct correct string/array on PHP side and then pass it to HighChart for charting?

Comment: Yes the array as is is fine in PHP. I have done it before in PHP, but I'm converting this code over to Yii2 and using the package mentioned above. I've looked at the package and not been able to find if anything in there alters the array